# Finding average of same key values of an associate array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, average

I've have an array such as

```
//$ary, $ary contains some 80 entries, I'm showing only the first 10
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 58
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [November 2012] => 84
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 83
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [November 2012] => 72
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [November 2012] => 47
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 93
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [November 2012] => 79
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [October 2012] => 70
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [November 2012] => 75
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [October 2012] => 59
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 67
        )
)
```

I'm able to get the total for each month using:

```
foreach($ary as $array)
{   
    foreach($array as $month=>$cent)
    {

        if(isset($abc[$month])) // prevent index warning
        {           
            $abc[$month] += $cent;
           // tried using $abc[$month] = $abc[$month]/2 but wrong values were returned
        }
        else
        {
            $abc[$month] = $cent;
        }
    }
}
```

This is resulting in

```
Array
(
    [December 2012] => 2195
    [November 2012] => 2159
    [October 2012] => 1631
)
```

But I'm unable to find a way to find the average value for each month. In my case, there are 31 instances of `December 2012`, 31 instances of `November 2012` and 25 instances of `October 2012`. Thus, I need to get hold of these `31`, `31`, and `25` values so that I can divide a month by that number.

I'm thinking something must be done inside `if(isset($abc[$month]))` loop to capture but haven't been successful so far. Is there any other way to get the average?

PS : I can't hardcode the month's name (October, November, December) for comparison purposes. They keep changing at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$eachMonth = array();
foreach($ary as $array)
{   
   foreach($array as $month=>$cent)
  {

    $eachMonth[$month][] = $cent;

    if(isset($abc[$month])) // prevent index warning
    {           
        $abc[$month] += $cent
    }
    else
    {
        $abc[$month] = $cent;
    }
  }
}
```

then for each month you can calculate average:

```
foreach( $eachMonth as $month => $values)
{
   echo $month.' : '.$abc[$month] / count($values);

}
```

Comment: That does work. +1 and accepting as answer. Moving `$eachMonth[$month][] = $cent` outside the `isset` loop did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$your_array = array(array("December 2012" => 58),
               array("December 2012" => 58)
              );

$res    = array();            
foreach($your_array as $val){
  $res[key($val)][] = $val[key($val)];
}

foreach($res as $k=>&$v){
   $v    = array_sum($v)/count($v);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Yeah....Even I feel it is lengthy, But the logic is pretty clear -> group the array based on month, then find the average of each of them. Let me see whether I can reduce the length of the code.